Dark theme on pop lists in Material UI
Im working on a project using Material UI and every list appears in dark theme when extended. Though it was fault of my computer theme but it continue happening with light mode.
By the way it should be vertical options instead of horizontal but that's not the big issue.
Here is the code with the MenuItem
<Select
  multiple
  labelId="select-multiple-checkbox-label"
  id="tags-select"
  value={tags}
  label="Tags"
  onChange={handleChangeMultiple}
  input={<Input />}
  variant="standard"
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
>
  {Tags.map((tag) => (
    <MenuItem key={tag} value={tag}>
      <Checkbox checked={tags.indexOf(tag) > -1} />
      {tag}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>

This is the theme
const theme = createTheme({
  colorSchemes: {
    light: true,
  },
});

This is how it looks

The same happens with the navbar menu
{settings.map((setting) => (
  <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
    <Typography sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      {setting}
    </Typography>
  </MenuItem>
))}


No css files used
